# Symfony http_cache and APC

Tags: symfony, caching, apc

First of all, sorry if this question's been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer on stackoverflow or anywhere else.

I'm using APC and Symfony's reverse proxy cache.
The app is hosted in a shared environment with limited apc.shm_size. Http_cache files are cached through APC which leads to bloating APC cache, APC full counts and of course an  important adverse impact on performance.

Does it make sense to cache the http_cache directory in APC anyway?
Or should the http_cache directory be excluded through an APC filter?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion reverse proxy cache makes sense only with Varnish. The Varnish is working just before the apache layer and bounces requests when it has a prepared response. You can find more information about ESI and Varnish in documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html

APC stores other kind of data - it can be related to Doctrine, and the Doctrine automatically puts results from database to the APC. Of course you can store more information - objects or arrays, but you will need to do it by hand.

In conclusion, it makes sense to store http_cache in Varnish because it is dedicated for reverse proxy cache - APC is purposed to store data like objects, values or arrays.